# Divide big sails js project

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I have a big Sails project that regroups 3 main parts : two front-end (depending on the user) and one back-end. My question is, what would be the best structure? For example in Rails you would have 1 project with 3 engines. But what about Sails?

Thanks!

Guillaume